# MVC.NET: define a strongly typed HTML Helper for DropDownList

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to find out how I could define my own HtmlHelper for creating a dropdownlist. I have the following scenarion: I am using the select2 jQuery plugin (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) for multiple selects with search and better interface. My Model has x id's of tags associated. As I understand it, these tags can only get a value when an Html helper like @Html.DropDownListFor() is used? I would like to

- write pure html and somehow tell it the value has to be stored in the list of tag-id's in my model

  **OR**
- make an HTML Helper which can achieve the same effect.

Currently I have this, but I see no way of passing the selected values to the model when the form gets posted:

```
<div>
        <label>Kies je thema's (maximum 2):</label>
        <select id="select2select" multiple style="width: 500px">
            @foreach (var top in ((List<Topic>)ViewBag.TopIds).Where(top => top.MainTopic == null))
            {
                <option value="@top.TopicId" class="optionGroup">@top.Name</option>
                foreach (var subTopic in top.SubTopics)
                {
                    <option value="@subTopic.TopicId" class="optionChild">@subTopic.Name</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
    </div>
```

How can I get the selected value in the property in my list while keeping this structure?

Extra: as you can see my options have classes, this is because I have Main tags and subtags. Users can choose either main tags or subtags, so I can't work with `<optiongroup>` because they 'groups' have to be selectable. I give them, depending on their class, a different format using select2 format.

Comment: add name attribute in select tag with your property name and you 'll get comma separated values during posting a form...

Comment: Oh gonna try that! Thanks! But does the property need to be a string or can it be a List<int> ?

Comment: mvc does support this binding .. take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468279/posting-a-model-containing-a-list-in-mvc-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code to rectify the problem

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => top.SubTopics, new SelectList(top.SubTopics, "TopicId", "Name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of ways you can do this.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => top.SubTopics, new SelectList(top.SubTopics, "TopicId", "Name"))

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.SubTopics, Model.SubTopics, null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "ui search selection dropdown clearable", @clearable = "", @id = "Model_SubTopics" })
```

These two can have issues with changing html Attribute "name" values for different model binding.

you can use a Tag Helper to do it the more modern way.

```
<select asp-for="Model.SubTopics" asp-items="@Model.SubTopics"  class="ui search selection dropdown clearable" ></select>
```

This way will take the pre-configured value if you have model binding for the input form.